# Comparing an array with an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to build a simple statistics tool that receives bunch of CSVs, parses them into JSONs, makes a few cross-data actions and outputs a new CSV with formatted statistics.
I'm quite new to JS and I got stuck while trying to cross data between an object and and an array.

After the parsing, I receive a big object (stats) formatted like this:

```
{
  'operator_1':
    conversions:
     [
       { 
         id: '3f002ab58',
         date: 13/03/2016
       },

       { 
         id: '4d002fb18',
         date: 14/03/2016
       }
      ]
    'opertor_2':
    conversions:
     [
       { 
         id: '1e03021149',
         date: 21/03/2016
       },

       { 
         id: '4bbc102fb18',
         date: 11/03/2016
       }
      ]
}
```

And I have another array (let's say countries_array[]) that looks like this:

```
[
  {id : '4bbc102fb18', country : 'russia'},
  {id : '33f3897300a', country : 'australia'},
  {id : '4d002fb18', country : 'usa'}
]
```

What i'm trying to do is to go over countries_array[], find all the occurrences of its' id's inside the big object (stats), and then attach the country property to the right corresponding operator's object's conversion array. So after i'll do attach_countries(stats,countries_array[]) I'll receive the same object (or a new one, it doesn't matter in this case) that looks like this:

```
{
  'operator_1':
    conversions:
     [
       { 
         id: '3f002ab58',
         date: 13/03/2016
       },

       { 
         id: '4d002fb18',
         date: 14/03/2016,
         country : 'usa' //usa was added
       }
      ]
    'opertor_2':
    conversions:
     [
       { 
         id: '1e03021149',
         date: 21/03/2016
       },

       { 
         id: '4bbc102fb18',
         date: 11/03/2016,
         country : 'russia' //russia was added
       }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you tried, and how did it come up short?

Comment: Does the big array need to be split into two operators? or more? Also it seems you are missing a `,` between the two operators.

Comment: Those are not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you provided for your object is invalid. Assuming the operator properties are objects having `conversions` as their property, you could use the ES6 solution below. It first builds a hash to avoid you have to iterate over the countries each time, but can access them directly by id:

```
const hash = new Map(countries_array.map( item => [item.id, item.country] ));

Object.keys(stats).forEach(key => {
    stats[key].conversions.forEach(item => {
        if (hash.has(item.id)) item.country = hash.get(item.id);
    });
});
```

```js
var stats = {
    operator_1: {
        conversions: [
           { 
             id: '3f002ab58',
             date: '13/03/2016'
           },

           { 
             id: '4d002fb18',
             date: '14/03/2016'
           }
        ],
    },
    operator_2: {
        conversions: [
           { 
             id: '1e03021149',
             date: '21/03/2016'
           },

           { 
             id: '4bbc102fb18',
             date: '11/03/2016'
           }
        ]
    }
};

countries_array = [
  {id : '4bbc102fb18', country : 'russia'},
  {id : '33f3897300a', country : 'australia'},
  {id : '4d002fb18', country : 'usa'}
];

const hash = new Map(countries_array.map( item => [item.id, item.country] ));

Object.keys(stats).forEach(key => {
    stats[key].conversions.forEach(item => {
        if (hash.has(item.id)) item.country = hash.get(item.id);
    });
});

console.log(stats);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Amazing, Thanks!
The syntax was quite slippery indeed.. sorry for that. But your solution worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your JSON code that had errors. Ignored your "date" format.

```js
var stats = {
  'operator_1': {
    conversions:
     [
       { 
         id: '3f002ab58',
         date: 13/03/2016
       },
       { 
         id: '4d002fb18',
         date: 14/03/2016
       }
      ]
    },
    'opertor_2': {
    conversions:
     [
       { 
         id: '1e03021149',
         date: 21/03/2016
       },

       { 
         id: '4bbc102fb18',
         date: 11/03/2016
       }
      ]
      }
}

var countries = [
  {id : '4bbc102fb18', country : 'russia'},
  {id : '33f3897300a', country : 'australia'},
  {id : '4d002fb18', country : 'usa'}
]

countries.map(country => {
 Object.keys(stats).map(operator => {
    let match = stats[operator].conversions.find(item => item.id === country.id)
    if (match) match.country = country.country
  })
})

console.log(stats)
```

Comment: ...but @trincot offered about 2x faster solution